# Create a dotm with a custom word ribbon button

Tags: ms-word, word-template, custom-ui

I have a VBA script that, when ran, allows the user to open up a range of documents, then a UserForm appears. After the text boxes on the UserForm are filled out, the data is then used to create a Footer on the documents that the user selected. I currently have this saved as a docm. If I create a button in the Ribbon to run this Macro, how do I go about bundling the whole thing together into one template that I can share with user's in my company? We currently run Office O365.

I'm aware that this can be done with a dotm file. Do I just save the docm as a dotm (are there any extra steps needed to convert to dotm)? How do I get the dotm to contain both the macro and the button in the ribbon that will run it?

I am very new to VBA scripting and coding in general (only been at it for about 2 weeks) so I'm not really up on all the terminology. I've seen some how-tos online that involve adding XML code to the docm but I can't figure out how to apply what they are doing to my specific situation.

The end result I'm looking for is to have a dot or dotm file that I can copy to the users' STARTUP file in word and it have the macro button loaded into the ribbon automatically.

Currently I have changed the dotm file to a zip file and I have added a customui.xml file to the zip file. Then I turn I removed the zip extension turning it back into a dotm. Here is the code that I have for the customui.xml file (I've also tried removing the "mso:" from each line but it still doesn't work):

```
    <mso:cmd app="Word" dt="0"/>
<mso:customUI xmlns:x1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui/macro" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <mso:ribbon>
        <mso:qat/>
        <mso:tabs>
            <mso:tab id="mso_c1.F7BE67B" label="HFA" insertBeforeQ="mso:TabInsert">
                <mso:group id="mso_c2.F7BE67B" label="Footer" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:button idQ="x1:openAllfilesInALocation_0_F7D1806" label="Create Footer" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="openAllfilesInALocation" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>
            <mso:tab id="mso_c1.59115D6" label="HFA Footer" insertBeforeQ="mso:TabDeveloper">
                <mso:group id="mso_c2.59115D6" label="Footer Creation" imageMso="FrameCreateAbove" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:button idQ="x1:openAllfilesInALocation_0_594B1AA" label="Create Footer" imageMso="FrameCreateAbove" onAction="openAllfilesInALocation" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

Here is the code from the .rels file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="someID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

When I add this dotm file to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP
it does not add the custom button to the ribbon, however the macro is present.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've created a number of these. They can be found on my Downloads page. https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#AddIns You are welcome to examine them. Start with "Modify the Ribbon - It Doesn't Take Rocket Science" by Greg Maxey. https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html This is XML programming combined with vba. Good technical specs on the commands, start with Ribbon X which is an older book but still applicable. https://web.archive.org/web/20180417112605/http://site.thehousewaresstore.com/oodle/AccessBooks/Wiley.RibbonX.Customizing.the.Office.2007.Ribbon.Jan.2008.pdf

Comment: You have a .dotm file which contains your Ribbon XML and any macros you want to be using. When it is stored in the Word Startup Folder, the ribbon modifications become part of the user interface in all documents. - https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm#PageStart -- https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global

Comment: After I wrote, I realized that most of my downloads do not have Ribbon customization. I do a lot more that simply add things to the QAT. Here are a few of my Add-Ins that have ribbon modifications done through XML. You are welcome to look at them. https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#FileNewClassic, https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#GenderToolbar, https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ContinuousPageNumbering, https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ChrisWoodman - - Read Greg Maxey's page before you try to figure out how these work, though.

Comment: Final note: this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. It is more about how to tweak code that you have already written than abut broad questions. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: I added the code I have to the original question.